# work out days in week across date range

Tags: c#, recursion

I am trying to work out how many days are in each week across a date range. my week runs **sat-sat**. 
I have a startdate, and a duration (and a week number - as actually I want to return the number of days in a particular week across the range)

**edit:** I will try to be a bit more clear. I do indeed want the days before the next saturday across a date range ..  so yes when its a range that is long enough the second week will always be 7 days. however the last week will be the number of days remaining of the duration if the duration does not stretch until a saturday.. hopefully the answers below will shed some more light.. maybe not though.
week number is the week across the date range. nothing to do with where weeks fall in the year.
**worth noting** that the arrivalDate can be a saturday so if its a saturday start and 7 duration would need to return 7...

so basically if I have say

```
arrivalDate = 29/06/2014 (sunday)
weeknumber = 1
duration = 17
```

I need it to return 6

if the weeknumber is 2 it should return 7

if the weeknumber is 3 it should return 4

I have this so far, which I know is far from ideal - expecting a bit of recursion might work best but my brain isnt quite functioning as yet..

```
public static int DaysInWeek(DateTime arrivalDate, int weekNumber, int duration)
{
    int ret =0;
    List<int> arr = new List<int>();
    int leftOver = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= duration; i++)
    {
        if (arrivalDate.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            int x = i;
            arr.Add( x - arr.Sum() );
            leftOver = duration - arr.Sum();
        }
    }
    if (leftOver < 7 && leftOver > 0) arr.Add( leftOver );
    if (arr.Count == 0) ret = duration;
    else ret = arr[weekNumber - 1];

    return ret;
}
```

thanks

Comment: could you explain a bit more what you want to do? i dont get it

Comment: not clear to me. `number of days in any week` is 7 for me... and what is `weeknumber`? is that your own defined number as weeknumber 1 should be the first week of the year.

Comment: I have to agree with Stefan, although as a side note your list of ints is going to be y, 7, 7, 7... where y is the number of days before the next Saturday from the arrivalDate.  I don't know if that's what you are trying to go for.

Comment: if startdate is 29/6/2014, is the duration the count of workdays (mon to sat)? so first duration workday would be monday the 30/6, second tuesday the 1/7? first week would go from mon to sat (7/7), second week would go from mon to sat (9/7 - 14/7) which would be also 6 days, third week would go from monday to friday (17 workdays reached) which would be 5 days and not 4, am i right?

Comment: @stefan: nothing to do with working days.. just says that fall within a sat-sat week. so if the date started on a wednesday and the duration was 16 say, the first week would be wed-sat, 2nd sat-sat, 3rd would be  sat-fri - so I would want 3,7,6 as the lengths of the weeks - possibly using the term 'week' was misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution based on CeejeeB's solution, that handles Saturday as first day and weekNumbers that are outside the timespan defined by duration.

```
public static int DaysInWeek(DateTime arrivalDate, int weekNumber, int duration)
{
    // Handle a Saturday as start day
    var daysInFirstWeek = arrivalDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ? 7 : DayOfWeek.Saturday - arrivalDate.DayOfWeek;

    // First week
    if (weekNumber == 1) return Math.Min(duration, daysInFirstWeek);

    // Other week
    var start = daysInFirstWeek + ((weekNumber - 2) * 7);
    return Math.Max(0, Math.Min(7, duration - start));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
public static int DaysInWeek(DateTime arrivalDate, int weekNumber, int duration)
{
    const int daysInAWeek = 7;

    //get the value of Saturday (your week start day)
    int firstDayOfWeekIndex = (int)DayOfWeek.Saturday;

    //get the day of week of the first day
    int startDay = arrivalDate.DayOfWeek;

    //Find out number of says until next Saturday (days in first week)
    int daysInFirstWeek = (startDay + firstDayOfWeekIndex) % daysInAWeek;

    //Get the 'Full Weeks', that have all 7 days in the duration
    int fullWeeks = (duration - daysInFirstWeek) / daysInAWeek;

    //Get any leftover days
    int leftover = duration - daysInAWeek * fullWeeks - daysInFirstWeek;

    //Get total number of weeks (complete or otherwise)
    int totalWeeks = 1 + fullWeeks + (leftover > 0 ? 1 : 0);

    //return accordingly
    if(weekNumber > totalWeeks)
       return 0;
    else if(weekNumber == 1)
       return daysInFirstWeek;
    else if(weekNumber == totalWeeks)
       return daysInLastWeek;
    else return daysInAWeek;
}
```

No list, no iteration, no recursion needed.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorter version that satisfies your 3 test cases. No recursion needed. Basically the result is going to fall into 1 of 3 outcomes. The results are always going to be either part of the first week, the whole of a middle week or part of the last week.
This code deals with the three senarios.

```
public static int DaysInWeekNew(DateTime arrivalDate, int weekNumber, int duration)
{
    var offset = arrivalDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ? 7 : DayOfWeek.Saturday - arrivalDate.DayOfWeek;

    //First Week
    if (duration < offset) return duration;
    if (weekNumber == 1) return offset;

    //Middle Week
    var start = offset + ((weekNumber - 2) * 7);
    if (start + 7 < duration) return 7;

    //Last Week
    return duration - start;
}
```

UPDATED based on comments

Comment: DaysInWeekNew(new DateTime(2014, 6, 29), 3, 18) should be 5 i think, but it returns 3

Comment: think its close enough but should be 
if (start + 7 < (duration-offset)) return 7;
and
return start + 7 - (duration-offset);
although also struggles with a saturday start

Comment: I have updated my answer now to correct the scenario Stefan mentioned

Comment: what should be the value if saturday is a start day?

Comment: depends on the duration - the duration if its (the duration) less than 7 or 7

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
    public static int DaysInWeekNew(DateTime arrivalDate, int weekNumber, int duration)
    {
        var offset = DayOfWeek.Saturday - arrivalDate.DayOfWeek;
        //First Week
        if (offset == 0) offset = 7; //if startdays is saturday

        if (weekNumber == 1) return offset > duration ? duration : offset;

        int numberofmiddleweeks = (duration - offset) / 7; //floor
        //middleweeks
        if (weekNumber - 1 <= numberofmiddleweeks) return 7;//-1 for the first week    
        //Last Week
        return duration - offset - numberofmiddleweeks * 7;            
    }
```

EDIT: updated for startday saturday